# Javascript and ASP.NET with Visual Studio OnMouseOver Control Validation Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onmouseover

I just started working with Javascript and I ran into an error with Visual Studio stating, "Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'onMouseOver' is not a valid attribute of element 'Button'".  Basically, I entered onMouseOver="this.style.color='Red'" within the HTML code of a button control.  When I run my web project, the mouse over command works just fine; however, the error message is posted.

What should I do to resolve this error or is this error message not critical, since the mouse over command works well?

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: I noticed that this is not an error, but rather a message, so I should restate my question.  Should I worry about this message?  Is there a way to make VS accept the attribute?  Eventually, I will have many of these messages, since I will be using mouse over often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not like javascript within `<asp:..>` server control tags. Their preferred approach is to wire up the javascript in code-behind, for example by using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx) explaining their official approach.

I believe that the purpose for doing it this way may be so that ASP.Net can render browser-specific code.

But hey, if your code works.......

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out the article.  I was actually going to post another question about Javascript functions and code-behind.  I cannot  figure out how to create a file to add javascript code-behind in Visual Studio.